# On click function parameters Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to pass one parameter to a function by knockout click binding. If i try sending it without binding, it works.

Here is the fiddle of the working code without binding:

https://jsfiddle.net/Obviously/ev0Lcx7q/4/

But if I try binding like this, it does not works:

```
<input class="sometextbox">
 <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.someFunction.bind($root,$(this).siblings('input').val())"> Search! 
</button>
```

I get the error at  $(this), JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'siblings'

Comment: Rather than trying to get jQuery and Knockout to 'play nice' within this Knockout binding, why not pass just `$(this)` to `someFunction` and then get jQuery to evaluate `parameter.siblings('input').val()` within `someFunction`.  Might be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Heart wants what it wants.... But no, In my particular case I do not want to touch the js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$element` gives you access to the current element in a Knockout binding.

```
<input class="sometextbox">
<button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.someFunction.bind($root, $($element).siblings('input').val())"> Search! </button>
```

Note that using jquery in a Knockout binding is not a common approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't really making correct use of knockout. Using it to add click events when (as your fiddle example shows) a regular in-line event definition works fine, but ignoring the ability of knockout to bind that textbox to some variable in your program seems like you're getting things backwards.
Something more like this is how I think knockout was intended to be use:

```
<script>
ko.applyBindings(model);
function myModel(){
   this.myInput = ko.observable('some default value');
}
function myClick(){
   alert(model.myInput());
}
</script>

<input class="textbox" data-bind="value: myTextArea">
<button data-bind="click: myClick">Go</button>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the way  i am using knockout. If i pass a value by id, it works just fine. It is the only "$(this)" thing causing problem.

Comment: Okay but there is strong argument for keeping any in-line code short and sweet. `this` no longer refers to the element clicked as it would in a regular in-line onclick. Instead it refers to the view model used by `ko.applyBindings`. Is there any reason why using a traditional `onclick` like you did in the fiddle is not appropriate?

Comment: I need bindings that is why I can not use the normal onclick .